# Input undefined when sending post request to the nodejs api using react and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to make a post request to an API that I created with mysql and node js using react and axios. But when I input in the data the response i get is 'undefined'.
When I put the data with postman, it works. I tried to log the data that I sent  with my browser and I saw them.
So I think that maybe the structure

When i console.log the data in the browser, I can figure out those data

```js
adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
    data: "{"etudiants":{"name":"Fenohasina 
    Andrainiony","lastname":"fenohasina","birthdate":"12-12-12"}
```

So i think that maybe, the structure of the data I sent is different to the structure I can receive on my API because on my API: it is just

```js
{"name":"Fenohasina 
    Andrainiony","lastname":"fenohasina","birthdate":"12-12-12"}
```

`Is this the problem?`

This is the api code:

> 

```js
app.post('/etudiants/add', (req, res)=>{
    const   {name,
            lastname,
            birthdate,
           
    } = req.query;
    const queryInsert =`insert into etudiants (name, lastname, birthdate) values('${name}', '${lastname}', '${birthdate}')`
    connection.query(queryInsert, (err, rows, fields)=>{
        if(err) {
            throw err
        }
        res.json(rows);
        res.end()
    })
```

}
}`

And the React Code:

```js
export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
            name:'',
            lastname:'',
            birthdate:'',
  }
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
const etudiants = {
      name: this.state.name,
      lastname:this.state.lastname,
      birthdate:this.state.birthdate,

    };
  axios.post('http://localhost:8080/etudiants/add', {etudiants})
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  }
  handleName = event => {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    })}
  handleLastname = event => {
    this.setState({
      lastname: event.target.value,
    })}

  handleBirthdate = event => {
    this.setState({
      birthdate: event.target.value
    })}
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Person Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" id='name'value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleName} />
          </label>
          <label>
            Person Lastname:
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lastname'value={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.handleLastname} />
          </label>
          <label>
            Person birthdate:
            <input type="text" name="genre" id='birthdate'value={this.state.birthdate} onChange={this.handleBirthdate} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes the problem is with the data you send

It should be

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/etudiants/add', {...etudiants})
```

(*note the spread operator `...` so that your `etudiants` constant is expanded in the object you send. Otherwise it just creates a property named `etudiants` which contains the contents of your constant*)

---

Your code uses the short notation introduced in ES6

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions

---

additionally you could re-use a single method for your input handling since they all do the same thing. So `handleName`, `handleLastname` and `handleBirthdate` could be replaced by just

```
handleInput = event => {
  const {name, value} = event.target;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
}
```

---

finally i think

```
<input type="text" name="genre" id='birthdate'
```

should really be

```
<input type="text" name="birthdate" id='birthdate'
```

Comment: Thank you guys! That explain the issue i got in the first time: the birthdate was undefined.  Your method made my code more sample.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you are extracting the request data in the backend. In the react code, this is how you are making the request to the server:

`axios.post('http://localhost:8080/etudiants/add', {etudiants})`

The default behavior of Axios, when used like this, is to JSON serialize the request data(i.e `{etudiants}`) [Refrence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format).
In order to receive and use this data in the backend, you need to parse the JSON request body, if you are using a body-parser middleware [like this one](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), that should already be done for you. Then, you can extract the request body like this:

```
const { 
    name,
    lastname,
    birthdate,
   } = req.body.etudiants;
```

Note how I replaced `req.query` with `req.body` and the addition of `etudiants`.

Comment: Thank you OTZ for your help. We sloved it.